# Ubuntu Ctrl+A for all select - Cinnamon

Tags: cinnamon

I've installed cinnamon DE on Ubuntu 15.04 and now when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> it cursor goes to the first letter of the line. ( like in terminal ).

Is there way I can fix it?

Comment: In terminal, Ctrl + A will not work. Does it work in a text editor?

Comment: @Tim I fixed it changing keymap option Emac to default . 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered [in comments](https://askubuntu.com/questions/727965/ubuntu-ctrla-for-all-select-cinnamon?noredirect=1#comment1078942_727965) by [OP](https://askubuntu.com/users/269901/ruwan-ranganath):

> I fixed it changing keymap option Emac to default. Thanks.